# Using Jest, how do I spyon an extended component's method when unit testing a single file component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm currently trying to get a single file component (`ComponentB`) unit tested using Jest and vue-test-utils. `ComponentB` extends `ComponentA`, which has a method `update(product)` defined in it.

```
/* -------- Component B -------- */
<script>
import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
export default {
  extends: ComponentA,
  props: [...],
  data: () => {
    productData: {foo: 'bar', baz: 'shiz'}
  },
  methods: {
    updateProduct() {
      this.update(this.productData)
    }
  }
}
</script>

/* -------- Component A -------- */
<script>
export default {
  props: [...],
  data: () => {...},
  methods: {
    update(productData) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I then attempt a unit test in which I `shallowMount()` my `ComponentB` and try to `jest.spyOn` that `update(productData)` method that is defined in `ComponentA`. The test looks like this:

```
it('calls update with data when input is added to the field', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(ComponentA, 'update);
  const wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentB, { propsData: { ... } });
  const contractIdInput = wrapper.find('#contract-id-input > b-form-input');    

  contractIdInput.element.value = 'foobar';
  contractIdInput.trigger('input')

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...someDataHere...)
});
```

When I run this test, I get a `Cannot spy the update property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`.

I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working, though I *do* have some ideas.

First, because I am `shallowMount()`ing my `ComponentB`, it isn't going to know anything about its parent component, and thus not have access to the `update(productData)` method that is defined on `ComponentA`.

Second, perhaps I'm not calling `jest.spyOn()` at the right time, and should instead call it after I create the wrapper object of `ComponentB`. However, I tried changing this around and didn't have any success or different behavior.

So my question is, how do I spy on a method that is provided by an extended component when I am shallow mounting the component under test?

Answer (score 21):

Just to add to the answer above of @user2718281, [`SetMethods`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setmethods) it's deprecated, so you better define the spyOn pointing to the ComponentB before instantiating like this:

```js
// create a spy before the instance is created
const spySomeMethod = jest.spyOn(ComponentB.methods, 'someMethod')

const spyUpdate = jest.spyOn(ComponentB.methods, 'update')

const wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentB, { propsData: { ... } });

// your tests ...

// verify the spy was called
expect(spyUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();

// remove the spy
spyUpdate.mockReset();
```

And about the question maybe you are forgetting to add the `ComponentA.methods` like this:

```
const spySomeMethod = jest.spyOn(ComponentB.methods, 'someMethod')
```

but if you want to test some lifecycle method event like `mounted` or `created` remove the `.methods` like this:

```
const spySomeMethod = jest.spyOn(ComponentB, 'created')
```

Comment: For those running into this by googling: For me spying on the wrapper worked better than the Component itself. See code @kevin answer below. With "better" I mean that the spy cant track calls from another fellow methods and the like.

Comment: @telion But what if you need to spy during the mount process itself?

Comment: I had this Issue 3 years ago, so I don't know the in's and out's of this Issue anymore. But in generally you need to spy on the Component itself and not the wrapper, since the wrapper is not created yet. Also note that this Issue was while using Vue2 and not Vue3 so a lot has been updated in all this time, so I recommend opening a new question.

Answer (score 8):

`ComponentA` is a component definition with `update` as a child of the `methods` attribute so `update` will not be found on `ComponentA` or `ComponentB`. `spyOn` should be applied on the instance of the component instead.

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentB, { propsData: { ... } });

// create a spy on the instance method
const spyUpdate = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'update')

// replace the instance method with the spy
wrapper.setMethods({ update: spyUpdate });

// your tests ...

// verify the spy was called
expect(spyUpdate).toHaveBeenCalled();

// remove the spy
spyUpdate.mockReset();
```

Comment: What if you are testing the `mounted` method? Cant set the mock/spy after `shallowMount`...

Comment: @wilmol my answer it's covering the case you are mentioning because I'm setting the spy before mounting so should be called after the "shallowMount" method and will work, let me know if that works https://stackoverflow.com/a/62583728/1549677